# Couple of useful MySQL SUM questions

Tags: mysql

If I was to have some MySQL such as:

```
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(`num1`) + SUM(`num2`) FROM database.table WHERE `id` = :id");
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $ident, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
        $sum2 = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

And lets assume that the respective values of `num1` is 20 and `num2` is null, should I expect to receive a $sum2[0][0] value of 20 or null?

Also when using SUM, should the prepared select be as is displayed or:

```
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(`num1` + `num2`) FROM database.table WHERE `id` = :id");
```

Or does it not particularly matter?

Comment: If any value is NULL, then the result is NULL. Try in the console or in Phpmyadmin with `select 1+null` or any other mathematic operation. If you use SUM on Mysql, you need to use also GROUP BY.

Comment: When you start to type *Couple of questions*,  please remember that this is a **question and answer** site. Note that neither **question** or **answer** is plural.

Comment: I believe there are two questions, which as it turned out were potentially related to the end result. One being using SUM and adding with NULL values and the other defining whether the prepared statement structure would have altered this in any way. If not, sorry for the confusion but it still looks like two relevant questions to myself...

Comment: Thanks as usual to my fantroll who always votes me down one for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MySQL `if` because `SUM(any)`+`NULL` =`NULL`

```
IF(num1 IS NULL,0,num1)
IF(num2 IS NULL,0,num2)
```

or use like that:-

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(num1), 0)
```

or use `IFNULL`

```
IFNULL(SUM(num1), 0)
```

or use `COALESCE`

```
COALESCE(SUM(num1), 0)
```

Comment: Success, much appreciated! Extensive options on the answer helped a lot also. :)

Comment: it's my pleasure :) @Cassandra

Answer (score 1):

`sum()` ignores `NULL` values.  So, it only returns `NULL` when *all* the values are `NULL`.

On the other hand, when you add two numbers, then the result is `NULL` if either is `NLLL`.

So, in the first query, if you only have one row, then the result is `NULL`, because `sum(num2)` is `NULL` and the addition has a `NULL` result.

In the second case -- with one  row -- then the value would also be `NULL`.  However, with multiple rows, it would end up ignoring rows where either column has a `NULL` value.

Comment: Ok so no matter what I do regarding my prepared select, and assuming that the id will only ever look at the result for one row, if either of the two values are NULL then my result will be NULL. Is there a way that I can get a NULL result to behave like a 0 result so that (in my example) 20 + NULL will act like 20 + 0 and equal 20?